# call to jquery inside bootstrap model

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have dynamic content inside a Bootstrap modal. It means that I have a number of buttons that open the modal and send it to different ID. The ID pulls data from the DB.

```
<a href="itinPage-secManage.view.php?act=new&itinID=3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manageSec-model">CREATE NEW SECTION</a>

<a href="itinPage-secManage.view.php?act=new&itinID=4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manageSec-model">CREATE NEW SECTION</a>
```

I have a script inside the modal. If I call to  "jquery-1.11.1.min.js" inside the modal then all the scripts work fine. But the problem is that the modal doesn't refresh when it's getting opened (same content displays with each opening). If I remove the jquery file from the modal then some scripts do not work.

Comment: can you share your modal?

Comment: Create a on click event on `<a>` tag and fetch data from the url and set it to the modal

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the sequence of calling jquery is correct i.e call jquery-1.11.1.min.js on top after that call bootstrap jquery. Hope so it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It matters in which order you call the resources in the head or top part if you will. Just cut the code line which calls jquery and put it above the call for bootstrap. Maybe make a fiddle or something so people can check to see what's wrong